# How to complete multiple ajax calls before starting next chained function?

Tags: ajax, rest, sharepoint, promise, .when

I can get the emails, usernames, etc of multiple users in a SharePoint person picker control. Unfortunately, Id is not one of the available values. To get this, I'm assuming you need to perform multiple ajax calls, and in some cases you need to ensure these calls complete before performing another function.

I've experimented with when.done, when.apply.done and promises.all variations with no luck. I'm just not doing it right.

This is how I populate the emails array from my people picker control:

```
var ToCon = $("div[title='To Contacts'] > input").val();
var Fjson = JSON.parse(ToCon);
for (var i = 0; i < Fjson.length; i++) {
  EmailArray.push(Fjson[i].EntityData.Email);
}
```

Here is my function to get the users Id based on their email address:

```
function GetUserId(X) {

        $.ajax({ 
            url: xhost + "/_api/web/SiteUsers?$select=Id&$filter=Email eq '" + X + "'",
            type: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", }, //verbose
            success: function (data) {
                var xuserid = data.d.results[0].Id;
                return xuserid;
            },
            error: function (error) { alert(JSON.stringify(error)); }
        });
    }
```

How do I call the GetUserId(X) function for each item in EmailArray, AND make sure it completes before moving on to another chained function?

Answer (score 1):

one dirty way is to use "async:false" in your ajax call.
this would make ajax requests synchronous.

Promise should also work if you implement it correctly. 
use jQuery's Deferred for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: Played with promise.all, but couldn't get syntax right for my use case. Will try to post some examples, however embarrassing they are. Try to keep laughter to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Try below script logic.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myClassA() {
            this.myAsynchronousMethod = function (arg) {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/SiteUsers?$select=Id&$filter=Email eq '" + arg + "'",
                        type: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", }, //verbose
                        success: function (data) {
                            var xuserid = data.d.results[0].Id;
                            resolve(xuserid);
                        },
                        error: function (error) { reject(error); }
                    });
                });
            };
        }

        function main() {
            var testEmails = ["email", "email", "email"];
            var action = [];            
            for (var i = 0; i < testEmails.length; i++)
                action.push((new myClassA()).myAsynchronousMethod(testEmails[i]));

            Promise.all(action).then(function (response) {
                debugger;                
                for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    //to do
                }                    
            });
        }
    </script>
    <input id="Button1" onclick="main();" type="button" value="button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for all promises to complete using $.when.apply as you mentioned.  Here's the syntax:

```
var promises = [];

promises.push(loadSomeData());
promises.push(loadMoreData());

$.when.apply($, promises)
.fail(function(err)  {
    console.log(err);

})
.done(function (result1, result2)  {
    console.log(result1);
    console.log(result2);
});
```

Notice that in the done call, there are 2 arguments, which match the number of promises you added in the array.  The first promise is the first argument, second promise is the second argument and so on.

Here's another way you can get the user using JSOM:

```
function getUser(email) {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var user = context.get_site().get_rootWeb().ensureUser(email);
    context.load(user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
        console.log("Success: " + user.get_id());
    }, function (sender, args) {
        console.error(args.get_message());
    });
}
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    getUser("my@email.com");
}, "SP.js")
```

Also, if you want a better way to deal with all these promises, have a look at [jQuery Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/).  You can create your own promises and resolve them when the calls have finished.

```
function getUserAsPromise(email) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var user = context.get_site().get_rootWeb().ensureUser(email);
    this.context.load(user);
    this.context.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) {
            deferred.resolve(user);
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            deferred.reject(sender, args);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise();
}
getUserAsPromise("my@email.com")
    .fail(function (sender, args) {
        console.error(args.get_message());
    })
    .done(function (user) {
        console.log("Success: " + user.get_id());
    });
```